# How can i delete a specific row from SQL server database using jTextField(Jframe) in netbeans?

Tags: java, sql

If i insert  String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='8272828'"
then data deleted from the database but in this case(JtextField1) data is not deleted,can any one help me how can i solve this?No error come ,dialog box show data deleted from database but actually not data deleted.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=student;integratedSecurity=true";

        Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "delete data from database");
        Statement statement = myCon.createStatement();

       // create a Statement from the connection
        String id=jTextField1.getText();


        String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='id'";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);

        }
          catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());


        }
        }
```

Comment: Is your connection using autocommit? Try adding myCon.commit(); after the executeUpdate call.

Comment: use parameter instead of that string concat. you save yourself a lot of headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql statement should be

```
 String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='"+id+"'";
```

**not**

```
 String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='id'";
```

Comment: I try this   String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='+id+'"; But same problem again,,no row deleted from database

Comment: I also do as  String sql="DELETE FROM record22 WHERE [Student ID]='"+id+"'"; ,, but no effect same problem again

Comment: Student ID is in integer type and string e.g 197766Jrk like this

Comment: Yes ,I'll accept your answer,, after 4minutes later,, I can accept your answer in 4minutes

Comment: @JamesB thanks for the upvote and please delete those comments that are not relevant to the answer

Comment: @HameedKhan please delete all those comments that are not relevant to the answer like thanksssssssssssss,ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh